# Copy value of Radio Button Selectio to text box

Tags: javascript

I am trying to copy the value from the selected radio button to display in a text box. However, I can not get this to work. I have copied my code below.

Is anyone able to help me please?

```js
function sync()
{
  var n4 = document.getElementById('n4').checked;
  var n1 = document.getElementById('n1');
  n1.value = n4.value;
}
```

```html
<form action="" id="n4"  onkeyup="sync()">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" id"4" onkeyup="sync()"> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" onkeyup="sync()"> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other" onkeyup="sync()"> Other
</form>

<input type="text" name="n1" id="n1" >
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function sync(el)
{
  var n1 = document.getElementById('n1');
  n1.value = el.value;
}
```

```html
<form action="" id="n4">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" id"4" onchange="sync(this)"> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" onchange="sync(this)"> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other" onchange="sync(this)"> Other
</form>

<input type="text" name="n1" id="n1" >
```

Use `onchange` and pass the element and get value from it.

Answer (score 1):

I have changed a bit of code. First of all i used the onchange event. 
After that ive created an array of radio buttons with the same class name. 
Everytime a radio button changes it will loop and return the checked value in the input field.

```js
function sync() {
  var radios = document.getElementsByName('gender');
  for(var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++){
    if(radios[i].checked){
      n1.value = radios[i].value;
    };
  };
};
```

```html
<form action="" id="n4"  onkeyup="sync()">
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" id"4" onchange="sync()"> Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" onchange="sync()"> Female<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="other" onchange="sync()"> Other
</form>


<input type="text" name="n1" id="n1" >
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Please use the below to set the value. As per your code you are just assigning values to each other.

```
function sync()
{
var n4 = document.getElementById('n4').checked;
    document.getElementById("n1").value = n4;
}
```

Comment: The OP is setting the value of the textbox to the `value` property of a Boolean, which is undefined. Your code will only set the textbox's value to `true` or `false` depending on whether the first radio button is checked or not, which does not appear to be what the OP wants.